# Inserting nested entities with autoincrement using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have class with property of the same type (I will describe classes in C#, but this doesn't matter here)

```cs
class Exception
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public Exception InnerException { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see from the code above there is exception class with nested exception.

Let's create table for storing these exceptions

```
CREATE TABLE Exceptions
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Message] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    StackTrace NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    InnerExceptionId INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK__Exceptions_Id__Exceptions_InnerExceptionId
        FOREIGN KEY(InnerExceptionId) REFERENCES Exceptions (Id)
);
```

Of course I can create some code that just works: for example some stored procedures that takes TVP as argument and then loop though rows of TVP and inserts new rows one by one.

But are there any SQL code that can elegantly insert exceptions with nesting?

Comment: Couldn't work out what TVP was, but if you're inserting hierarchical data into a table with an autoinc int PK you have to do the insert, read the id, do the next insert.. in a loop. If you switch to using a guid pk  you can prepare the entire hierarchy in c# and insert in one go, as you can be reasonably certain of no guid collisions

Comment: @CaiusJard TVP is table-valued parameters. Here is [wiki on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/table-valued-parameters/info).

Comment: Could you provide some data that we can work with? Without data, I can't understand fully, what you are trying to do...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Could you please take a look at [my self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52594928/1548895)? Maybe it will help you with sample data.

Comment: May the autoincrement column be implemented by a sequence instead of IDENTITY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up creating stored procedure with TVP and cursor loops.

Here is my table-valued parameter definition:

```
CREATE TYPE ExceptionTableType AS TABLE
(
    [Message] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    StackTrace NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);
```

Here is stored procedure with cursor loop

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LogException
    @exceptions ExceptionTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cursor CURSOR;

    DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @stackTrace NVARCHAR(MAX);

    DECLARE @innerExceptionId INT = NULL;

    DECLARE @outputTable TABLE (Id INT);

    BEGIN
        SET @cursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [Message], StackTrace
        FROM @exceptions;

        OPEN @cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor
        INTO @message, @stackTrace;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Exceptions
            ([Message], StackTrace, InnerExceptionId)
            OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @outputTable (Id)
            VALUES
            (@message, @stackTrace, @innerExceptionId);

            SELECT @innerExceptionId = Id
            FROM @outputTable;

            FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor
            INTO @message, @stackTrace;
        END;

        CLOSE @cursor;
        DEALLOCATE @cursor;
    END
END
```

Example of stored procedure call via SQL:

```
DECLARE @exceptions AS ExceptionTableType;

INSERT INTO @exceptions
([Message], [StackTrace])
VALUES
('My exception', 'Some stack trace here'),
('My inner exception', 'Dummy data'),
('My inner exception 2', 'Dummy data 2');

EXEC LogException @exceptions;
```

Answer (score 8):

- Put your rows in some list/collection, assign surrogate id/rowno to each row, build relations between rows based on that id/rowno; you can start from 1 each time - it does not matter
- Push these data to db
- Insert all rows into persistent `Exceptions` table, obtain generated IDENTITY values linked to original surrogate id
- Convert links based on surrogate id into IDENTITY-based links, update target table

So, `@original_list` is supposed to be an input argument. Then you need a trick that `MERGE` does well - linking `src.id` to `dst.id` after insert. Then just convert old values into new. All commands are set-based, no loops.

```
DECLARE @original_list TABLE (
  surrogate_no int not null,
  msg varchar(100) not null,
  inner_surrogate_no int null
);

insert into @original_list (surrogate_no, msg, inner_surrogate_no)
values
  (1000, 'err 1000', null),
  (1010, 'err 1010->1000', 1000),
  (1020, 'err 1020', null),
  (1030, 'err 1030->1010', 1010)

-- args prepared, starting migration

DECLARE @migration TABLE (
  src_id int not null,
  dst_id int not null
)

merge Exceptions t
using @original_list s
on 1=0 --<< we are not looking for updates
when not matched by target then
  insert (message) 
  values (s.msg)
output s.surrogate_no, inserted.id ---<<< here is the main trick: src.id and matching dst.id
into @migration(src_id, dst_id)
;

-- now all error messages are inserted, but none of them have InnerExceptionId

update e set
  InnerExceptionId = mp.dst_id
from Exceptions e
inner join @migration m  --<< get original surrogate_no 
  on m.dst_id = e.id
inner join @original_list o --<< grab original row
  on o.surrogate_no = m.src_id
inner join @migration mp  --<< locate dst.id for inner_surrogate_no
  on mp.src_id = o.inner_surrogate_no
```

This is a common solution for such tasks. [Full source](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a24bf/4)

Final data:

```
| Id |        Message | StackTrace | InnerExceptionId |
|----|----------------|------------|------------------|
|  1 |       err 1000 |     (null) |           (null) |
|  2 | err 1010->1000 |     (null) |                1 |
|  3 |       err 1020 |     (null) |           (null) |
|  4 | err 1030->1010 |     (null) |                2 |
```

Treeview by recursive cte:

```
|                                        Message | Lvl | id | InnerExceptionID |
|------------------------------------------------|-----|----|------------------|
|                                       err 1000 |   1 |  1 |           (null) |
|                                       err 1020 |   1 |  3 |           (null) |
|                    err 1010->1000>>>(err 1000) |   2 |  2 |                1 |
| err 1030->1010>>>(err 1010->1000>>>(err 1000)) |   3 |  4 |                2 |
```

Note, sqlfiddle did not allow me to run MERGE inside bigger script (it was failing all the time with semicolon exception), so I turned @ tables into persistent tables and put merge into dynamic sql, but you don't need to do that on real server.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I've upvoted your solution, but unfortunately I was hoping to find something more compact and concise.

Comment: More compact? Well, let me know if you will find one. More compact then two-step  means one-step, right? )

Comment: As far as I see three steps here. Also this replacing of ids looks tricky for me. I'm not saying that your solution is bad, I just want something simpler that [I did myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52594928/1548895).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, First step is `MERGE`, second step is `UPDATE`. I'd say, that it is not so about the simplicity, i.e. number of lines of code, but about efficiency. It is usually more efficient to perform set-based operations, rather than cursor loops in SQL Server.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Exceptions will have very few number of nesting. So you won't notice any performance difference here. That's why simplicity is much more important in this case for me.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, well, I can think of only two ways to do it. (1) insert rows one-by-one as you did with the cursor (2) insert all rows at once and then fill in the auto-generated IDs appropriately in bulk as shown in this answer. There may be slight variations in the implementation, but I don't think there is any other significantly different method. Keep the bounty open, maybe somebody would suggest something else.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Awarding bounty for original and interesting solution.

Answer (score 3):

Some remarks:

- `ExceptionTableType` has no 'order' field, as such, when you load the information you presume that the order you read the records in is going to be the order they were created. This is by no means guaranteed and might actually do strange things to your results!
- The `InnerExceptoinId` column feels 'backward', it seems to mean 'When filled in, this record is the InnerException from the referenced record', while I somehow would expect that it's use should work the other way around: "When filled in, the referenced record is an InnerException of mine". Right now you need to scan the entire table to see if there is an InnerException for a given record, and then repeat over and over until nothing is found anymore.

Anyway, staying close to your solution I've created a set-based version. Not sure it's going to matter much performance-wise, but out of principle it's to be preferred over the cursor-based approach =)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LogException2
    @exceptions ExceptionTableType READONLY
AS

    DECLARE @rowcount int

    SELECT source_id = IDENTITY(int, 1, 1),
           insert_id = Convert(int, 0),
           Message,
           StackTrace
      INTO #loading
      FROM @exceptions
    -- really should have ORDER BY here!

    SELECT source_id = source_id + 0,
           insert_id
      INTO #feedback
      FROM #loading
    WHERE 1 = 2

    INSERT INTO Exceptions ([Message], StackTrace, InnerExceptionId)
    OUTPUT l.source_id, [inserted].Id INTO #feedback (source_id, insert_id)
    SELECT l.Message,
           l.StackTrace,
           NULL
      FROM #loading

    UPDATE upd
       SET InnerExceptionID = f.insert_id + 1
      FROM Exceptions upd
      JOIN #feedback f
        ON f.insert_id = upd.Id
       AND f.source_id <> 1 -- first row has no InnerExpectionId

    Return(0)

GO
```

Comment: PS: under the hood, my solution isn't much different than the one from 
Ivan Starostin (after all, we're solving the same problem); I'm simply using `INSERT` where he uses `MERGE`, otherwise the idea is fairly identical (which I didn't notice at the time I glanced through the then existing answers, but all in all he beat me by a couple of days =)

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches that come to mind. The first is to just serialize the whole exception (nesting and all) into XML or something, and store that down. I don't know specifically what you plan to do with the exceptions once their stored, but a serialized document is probably the most straight forward to implement. If need be, you could shred the XML later into a tabular format if that was more to your liking.

The other way would be to do sort of what you described, but don't flatten the hierarchy in SQL, do it in the application code. That way, by the time you're actually passing something into the procedure, you can do it all in a single set, rather than having to do the looping in SQL (where it's harder, and more expensive (literally)).

Working with hierarchical data in a relational database is a pain on the best days, so unless you have a very specific need to represent the exception chain in that manner, I'd try to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this matter before, and what I did was creating a table that handles all exceptions, and then used a scalar function to retrieve the exception message. Then, we managed everything from there. after that we just used the scalar function to retrieve the error message.

Here is a quick example :

```
CREATE TABLE tblError (
    ErrorID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
,   ErrorMsg VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL 
,   CONSTRAINT PK_tblError PRIMARY KEY(ErrorID) 
)

CREATE FUNCTION Error (@ErrorID VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @Error VARCHAR(8000)

    SELECT 
        @Error = ErrorMsg
    FROM 
        tblError
    WHERE 
        ErrorID = @ErrorID 

RETURN ISNULL(@Error , 'Undefined Error')
END 

INSERT INTO tblError (ErrorID, ErrorMsg)
VALUES 
('0x0000','Cannot Divide by ZERO')



DECLARE 
    @ErrorMessage           VARCHAR(250)
,   @Demo                   INT = 0



IF @Demo = 0
BEGIN 
    SET @ErrorMessage  = dbo.Error('0x0000')
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,11,1)
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(100 AS FLOAT)/@Demo 
END
```

for the ErrorID we defined our unique Sequence for different groups of errors. So, you could expanded as fit your needs.